# wildcard support for jacocoxmlreportspath property is not working as expected

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, wildcard, jacoco

As per the documentation it says this property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths" supports wildcards
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

But if I try to use wildcard like below, it is not working and showing code coverage as '0'.

sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=**/jacoco.xml
If I give absolute path to the jacoco.xml file then only it is working and showing code coverage.
Isn't it supposed to work with wildcards as the documentation says?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using `**` without telling it where to start and then give a subset of directories.

Update to `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=./**/jacoco.xml`